# Proof that function ln$\frac {(2-e^x)} {(3+2e^x)}$ is surjective...

Tags: calculus, functions, logarithms, eulers-number-e

I would appreciate some help with proving that function ln$\frac {(2-e^x)} {(3+2e^x)}$ is surjective...
I get $x = \text{ln}\frac {(2-3y)} {(3y+1)}$, but I don't know how to get from here on. What is the official result?
Thank you in advance for answers :)

Comment: actually it's not...

Comment: Put $x=\log2 $ and see the magic :)

Comment: You've gotten a couple of nice answers, but asking if a function "is surjective" needs qualification to be meaningful, namely surjective on *what*.  I'm guessing this problem came up in the course of solving something larger, but *lacking that context* it would not have an "official result."

Answer (score 2):

Let $x \in \mathbb R$. Let $y = e^x$ then $y > 0.$ Then we have

$$  \frac{2-0}{3-2 \cdot 0} = \frac 2 3>\frac{2-y}{3+2y}$$
since the function $t \mapsto \frac{2-t}{3+2t}$ decreases on $t > \frac {-2}{3}.$
Since the logarithm is an increasing function we have

$$ \ln \frac 2 3 > \ln \frac{2-e^x}{3+2e^x}$$

Therefore the function $f :\mathbb R \rightarrow  \mathbb R : x \mapsto \ln \frac{2-e^x}{3+2e^x}$ is not surjective since

$$ \text{Im} f \subset (-\infty, \ln \frac 2 3) \neq \mathbb R.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\ln\frac {(2-e^x)} {(3+2e^x)}$$
The domain of $f(x)$ is $(-\infty, \ln 2)$ and the range is $(-\infty, \ln(2/3))$and $$f'(x)=\frac{-7e^x}{(2-e^x)(3+2e^x)}<0$$ which is negative in the domain. So it is monotonically decreasing. Hence $f:(-\infty, \ln 2) \rightarrow (-\infty,\ln(2/3))$ is both Injective (one to one) and Surjective (onto). Hence it is Bijective.